# heightForRowAtIndexPath is not always called on a real device

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have my TableView with posts. The table should calculate a height for the cells, and it does correctly in my simulator(iPhone 5S), but in a real device(also 5S) it calculates only ones the app is loaded and never recalculates it again. Therefore I have my posts displayed with not right height. What could be the problem?

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    VKPost* currentPost = _posts[indexPath.row];
    return [VKPostCell actualHeightForCellWithPost:currentPost];
}
```

update: it seems not to work only on devices with iOS lower then 8.

Comment: Did the device and the simulator are running the same iOS version? Try to delete the app on the device and run a Clean on Xcode.

Comment: Tried this lots of times, no changes. The device's version is 7, the simulator's is 8. It would be so stupid if it is the problem. *starting to download 7 version simulator*

Comment: You are saying `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not calling at all? on the device

Comment: No, as i said it calculates it only ones, when the data is loading.(noticed by placing NSlog messages)

Comment: Are you calling `[UITableView reloadData]` anywhere? Your table view has no reason to call the method again unless you give it a reason.

Comment: Where should I put [tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Put it wherever you want the Table View to be reloaded, so any function that is modifying the values is the height for your cells.

Answer (score 0):

Are you retrieving data for `_posts` from *web service or anywhere*? _posts could be empty when heightForRow is called. Try to put a completion block in your ***get data for _posts* method**, and when it completes, call `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: Yes I retrieve data from web service. And I think I have the call.(sorry the code is not originally mine)
`-(void)loaderDidFinishedloading:(NSArray *)posts{
    [_posts addObjectsFromArray:posts];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
`
btw I found out that it works wrong only in ios7, in ios8 it works properly.